# Symbols for windows 7 to use offline

Tags: windbg, dump

I am looking for Win7 symbols offline.

I check all possible result on google - and nothing.
Someone can help me to find those symbols?

Last year I downloaded those symbols and now I can't find it.

Comment: they are outdated. use [symcheck to generate a manifest file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-a-manifest-file-with-symchk), go to a 2nd PC, fetch the symbols, copy them back to the offline system.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a matter of finding it on your hard disk, use [Everything](https://voidtools.com/) and type *Win7 symbols .msi*

If you need to download them again, you can find symbols for Windows 7 SP1 (7601) at
[Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842). Just click "Download" and choose the symbol files (1.6 GB).

Be aware that these symbols are for the original version of Windows 7 SP1 as of 2011-02-22. These symbols may have little in common with a recently updated system.

You may use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502183/how-can-i-set-windbg-to-automatically-download-all-the-symbols/23504558#23504558) to download all symbols for a recent installation.