# Windbg symbols for Windows XP

Tags: reverse-engineering, windbg

So I have a problem getting symbols (such as ntdll.pdb) for Windows XP x86.
I know that in the past you could download these symbols, but today you can only do this from the microsoft servers like mantioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg)
The problem is that my XP machine can't access the Internet. Is there any way to get the symbols offline? Maybe someone here has symbols in "c:\symbols" and can upload them?
Thank you very much

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23504558/480982

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SymChk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-symchk) from a WinDbg package compatible with Windows XP to generate a manifest file on the offline machine, then use that manifest file on another machine with Internet access to download the symbols. Quoting from the [Using a Manifest File with SymChk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-a-manifest-file-with-symchk) page:

> In some cases, you might need to retrieve symbols for files that are on an isolated computer; that is, a computer that is either not on any network or is on a network that has no symbol store. In that situation, you can use the following procedure to retrieve symbols.
>
> 1. Run SymChk with the /om parameter to create a manifest file that describes the files for which you want to retrieve symbols.
> 2. Move the manifest file to a network that has a symbol store.
> 3. Run SymChk with the /im parameter to retrieve symbols for the files described in the manifest file.
> 4. Move the symbol files back to the isolated computer.